# modify user input in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to take a user input, in this case as a search word. But when sending this input to an API, the string must not contain any spaces. I tried .trim but this seems to only remove any spaces before and/or after the string. Essentially, I need to force any amount of words other than one together, any thoughts on how this could be achieved would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getSearch(){
var welcomeMsg = document.getElementById('result');
var search_term = document.getElementById('floatingInput');
```

---

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput">
  <input type="button" value="click">
  <label for="floatingInput">Song title / artist name</label>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for this, for example:

```js
> 'foo bar'.replace(' ', '')
'foobar'
```

If there are expected to be many spaces, you can use a [global regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#using_global_and_ignore_with_replace):

```js
> 'foo bar baz otherfoo'.replace(/ /g, '')
'foobarbazotherfoo'
```

Finally, if you still want to see the word boundaries as suggested by @JoeKincognito, you can update the second argument from an empty space `''` to the separator of your choice, for example:

```js
> 'foo bar baz otherfoo'.replace(/ /g, '-')
'foo-bar-baz-otherfoo'
```

This will allow you to separate the search terms later if necessary, and will allow you to differentiate between users searching for e.g., `butter` and `fingers` from users searching for `butterfingers`

Comment: If you want to get it back to 2 words on the backend maybe replace with '_' instead of ''

Answer (score 2):

`string.replace()` method supports regex expression:

```
xxx.replace(/\s+/g, '') //xxx is an example string.
\s: matches any whitespace symbol
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't think of using `\s+`. If you are just removing the spaces it will end up the same as `replace(/ /g, '')`, but if you are using a separator instead, I like that `\s+` will dedupe extra spaces so that `'foo   bar'` would become e.g., `'foo-bar'` instead of `'foo---bar'`